# Debezium Kafka Connect - Error Loading Plugin From Confluent Hub via Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I've recently tried installing the [Debezium PostgreSQL Connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql) v1.6.0 via `confluent-hub`.

When the plugin is loaded, the connector fails to load, raised by `loadProperties` in `IoUtil`, per this error:

```
[2021-07-13 00:45:06,715] INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-postgresql (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
[2021-07-13 00:45:07,375] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector.version(PostgresConnector.java:47)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:387)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:392)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:362)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:406)
at io.debezium.util.IoUtil.loadProperties(IoUtil.java:491)
at io.debezium.util.IoUtil.loadProperties(IoUtil.java:521)
at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:19)
... 12 more
```

We essentially have one Dockerfile, where we run the following:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:1.6.0
```

Everything seems to build fine, and both the zookeeper and local broker is running fine. I have noticed similar behaviour in versions 6.1.1 and 6.2.0.

Can anyone provide any input?

---

**Steps to recreate this issue:**

1. Create a network, and run the **confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0** image with the supplied "zookeeper.env" file for environment variables:

```sh
$ docker network create --driver bridge my_network
$ docker run --platform="linux/amd64" -p "2181:2181" --name="zookeeper" --env-file=zookeeper.env --network=my_network confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
```

2. Run the **confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0** image with the supplied "broker.env" file for environment variables:

```sh
$ docker run -p "29092:29092" -p "9092:9092" -p "9101:9101" --platform="linux/amd64" --name="broker" --env-file=broker.env --network=my_network confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
```

3. Build a Docker image from the "Dockerfile" attached which uses the base **confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0** . This image will install **debezium-connector-postgresql:1.6.0** from Confluent Hub. Run it with the supplied "connect.env" file for environment variables:

```sh
$ docker build . --platform='linux/amd64' -t 'connect'
$ docker run -p "8083:8083" --platform="linux/amd64" --name="connect" --env-file=connect.env --network=my_network connect
```

Relevant `.env` files and the Dockerfile are hosted [on this Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexcu/9c46a5f946a025120ca2b89e67de5e2b).

---

**Platform details:**

- macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 / M1
- Docker 3.5.2 (66501)
- Docker Engine 20.10.7

---

**EDIT:** After further investigation, it appears that this behaviour there are multiple issues either installing manually or `confluent-hub`. These issues appear to be present in other plugins, such as the MySQL connector or even Confluent's own JDBC connector. There is a summary [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/common-docker/issues/117#issuecomment-881805933).

Comment: FWIW `cp-kafka-connect` is deprecated and you should use `cp-kafka-connect-base`. This won't fix your problem tho :)

Comment: Out of interest, does it work on non-amd64?

Comment: Thanks for the advice; yep, the `cp-kafka-connect-base` didn't work. This runs fine on my colleagues' amd64/Intel machines, but the qemu emulation seems to work perfectly fine on my M1 (besides a very occasional segmentation fault). Zookeeper and the Broker images seem to run fine too from the logs I see. Loading the plugin is the only exception...

Comment: Does it work with other Kafka Connect plugins?

Comment: Definitely seems to be an issue with the Debezium **Postgresql** plugin. Both the `debezium-connector-mysql:1.6.0` and `confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.0` connectors load fine.

Comment: Update: Installing manually outside `confluent-hub` works fine: https://gist.github.com/alexcu/9c46a5f946a025120ca2b89e67de5e2b#file-manual-dockerfile

This seems to load the plugin fine.

Comment: Update: this does not appear to be an issue with a Debezium plugin. I see similar behaviour with a JDBC plugin from Confluent ([docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/alexcu/9c46a5f946a025120ca2b89e67de5e2b#file-docker-compose-jdbc-confluent-hub-yml) and [logs](https://gist.github.com/alexcu/9c46a5f946a025120ca2b89e67de5e2b#file-connect-jdbc-confluent-hub-log))

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this is a possible problem with the M1 architecture. I ran into the same issue with my M1 Mac and moved to my intel Mac and it worked fine.